# Add www with URL show Wix.com page

Tags: php, html, dns, web, hosting

My website is hosted on godaddy
projectprayerwindow.com
it works fine
but when i type www.projectprayerwindow.com
it didn't show the required results.
Can anyone help with this.[image]

Comment: It looks like you need to follow those steps, like it says, and point your www subdomain to your godaddy IP.

Comment: my website is hosted on godaddy

Comment: Yes, but according to WHOIS your authoritative DNS servers are `ns1.wix.com` and `ns2.wix.com`. So you'll need to update them from there. Alternatively, you can change them to the GoDaddy nameservers. They provide directions at http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/664/setting-nameservers-for-your-domain-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Login to your wix account.


Than follow the below steps:**


1 :- Hover over subscriptions and click on domains in top menu.

2:- Next at the bottom of window in My Domains click on manage in which the above mention problem is occurring.

3:- In the next window click on advanced tab and click on manage.

4:- In Hosts table edit the IP for the corresponding URL and enter the correct IP Address in the relevant Field.

The changes will take almost an hour to be applied.